# Beautifulsoup error: "openpyxl.utils.exceptions.illegalcharactererror"

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I'm trying to extract texts from html files saved locally in my hard drive. And then paste them in each rows in an excel file. Doing this on Mac, here is the full code:

```
# install/import all prerequisites first
# from cgitb import text
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# create a question that asks how many files you have
i = 1
n = int(input("How many files ? "))
# final_n = n - 1


# the list of files
files = []


# the list of files only has 1 file contained by default
# while loop will create multiple files in the list so that I don't have to do the tedious work
while i <= n:
    files.append("folder/SplashBidNoticeAbstractUI (" + str(i) +").html")
    i = i+1


# load an existing Libreoffice Calc file
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Data"


# add the titles on the first row, each column with the respective title
ws.append(["DatePublished", "Closing Date", "Category", "Procuring Entity", "Approved Budget for the Contract", "Name", "Delivery Period", "Reference Number", "Title", "Area of Delivery", "Solicitation Number", "Contact"])


# the actual magic.
# extract desired data from the html files and then
# paste in the active Libreoffice Calc file

for i in files:
    with open(i, "r", errors="ignore") as html_file:
        content = html_file.read()  # does something
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")  # does something

        # extracts data from the webpages
        
        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayDatePublish") != None:
            datePublished = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayDatePublish").text
        else: datePublished = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayCloseDateTime") != None:
            cd  = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayCloseDateTime").text
        else: cd = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayCategory") != None:
            cat = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayCategory").text
        else: cat = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayProcuringEntity") != None:
            pro_id = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayProcuringEntity").text.replace("", "")
        else: pro_id = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayBudget") != None:
            abc = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayBudget").text
        else: abc = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblHeader") != None:
            name = soup.find("span", id="lblHeader").text.replace(" ", "_").replace("\n", "_")
        else: name = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayPeriod") != None:
            delp = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayPeriod").text
        else: delp = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayReferenceNo")!= None:
            ref_num = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayReferenceNo").text
        else: ref_num = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayTitle")!= None:
            title = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayTitle").text.replace(" ", "_").replace("\n", "_")
        else: title = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayAOD") != None:
            aod = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayAOD").text.replace("\n", "_")
        else: aod = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplaySolNumber") != None:
            solNr = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplaySolNumber").text
        else: solNr = ""

        if soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayContactPerson")!= None:
            contact = soup.find("span", id="lblDisplayContactPerson").text
        else: contact = ""

        # just an assurance that the code worked and nothing screwed up
        print("\nBid" + i)
        print("Date Published: " + datePublished)
        print("Closing Date: " + cd)
        print("Category : " + cat)
        print("Procurement Entity : " + pro_id)
        print("Name: " + name)
        print("Delivery Period: " + delp)
        print("ABC: " + abc)
        print("Reference Number : " + ref_num)
        print("Title : " + title)
        print("Area of Delivery : " + aod)
        print("Solicitation Number: "+ solNr)
        print("Contact: "+ contact)

        # pastes the data inside the calc file under the titles
        ws.append([datePublished, cd, cat, pro_id, abc, name, delp, ref_num, title, aod, solNr, contact])

# saves file so work is safe and sound
filename = input("filename: ") 
wb.save(filename + ".xlsx")

print("Saved into '" + filename + ".xlsx'.")
```

Running this code for all **37,820** html files.

I've tried updating my Python version from `3.9` to `3.10` and `3.11`. I've tried running both `python3 phase3.py` and just `python phase3.py`. I've also reinstalled `bs4` and `openpyxl`. Still, problem isn't fixed. Here is the error

```
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.illegalcharactererror
```

Comment: Catch the excetion and deal with it, openpyxl can't create worksheets otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl module raises this [`exception`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.exceptions.html#openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError) when you try to assign an ASCII control character (e.g, `"\x00"`, `"\x01"`, ..) to a cell's value. It means that at least one of your`html` files holds this kind of characters. So, you need to use [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to escape those.

Replace this :

```
ws.append([datePublished, cd, cat, pro_id, abc, name, delp, ref_num, title, aod, solNr, contact])
```

By this :

```
    try:
        list_of_vals= [datePublished, cd, cat, pro_id, abc, name, delp, ref_num, title, aod, solNr, contact]
        ws.append(list_of_valls)
    except openpyxl.utils.exceptions.illegalcharactererror:
        ws.append([cell_val.encode("ascii") for cell_val in list_of_vals]
```

*NB: Be aware of the indentation here.*